# iis metabase URL writer using C#

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I've a requirement to automate the manual process of IIS using C#.

The requirement is, from IIS URL Rewrite I'm adding a set of new rules manually.
Say adding an Inbound Rule, Match URL, Server Variables and Actions items.

Now how to automate this using C#.
I did some research and we can use "System.DirectoryServices namespace" and IS Metabase using MetaEdit or Metabase Explorer.

But not able to find any example or code related and we are using IIS 7.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Microsoft.Web.Administration is the way to go. Please forget about other APIs.

Comment: Below are the issue that I'm facing. `Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");` this is not setting my inbound rules at server level. Also I want to add a server variable and I want to use that variable inside inbound server variable, which is also not happening.